# ScopedTypeVariables fail to work with nested where-clauses?

Tags: haskell, type-variables

It's a horribly contrived example, but anyway... this typechecks:

```
newtype Foo c = Foo { runFoo :: c -> Bool }
newtype Bar c = Bar { runBar :: Int -> c }

foo :: Eq c => Bar c -> (c -> [c]) -> Bar (Foo c)
foo bar f = Bar res
 where res n = Foo judge
        where judge c = (c`elem`) . f $ runBar bar n
```

and works

> GHCi> let foo0 = foo (Bar id) (\n -> [n, n*2])
>   GHCi> map (runFoo $ runBar foo0 4) [1..10]
>   [False,False,False,True,False,False,False,True,False,False]

but if I add the obvious type signature to the local function `judge`,

```
foo :: Eq c => Bar c -> (c -> [c]) -> Bar (Foo c)
foo bar f = Bar res
 where res n = Foo judge
        where judge :: c -> Bool
              judge c = (c`elem`) . f $ runBar bar n
```

it fails with

```
Could not deduce (c ~ c2)
from the context (Eq c)
  bound by the type signature for
             foo :: Eq c => Bar c -> (c -> [c]) -> Bar (Foo c)
```

and so on. Hardly surprising in Haskell 98, but I'd think `ScopedTypeVariables` should allow to write such signatures, but apparently it doesn't. Is there a specific reason for this, is it intentional that it doesn't work with nested `where`s, and what workarounds are there if this turns up in a comparable real-word problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently you forgot to bring the type variable `c` into scope with an explicit `forall`,

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Foobar where

newtype Foo c = Foo { runFoo :: c -> Bool }
newtype Bar c = Bar { runBar :: Int -> c }

foo :: forall c. Eq c => Bar c -> (c -> [c]) -> Bar (Foo c)
foo bar f = Bar res
 where res n = Foo judge
        where judge :: c -> Bool
              judge c = (c`elem`) . f $ runBar bar n
```

compiles fine.

`ScopedTypeVariables` by itself doesn't bring the type variables from the signature into scope, only those with an explicit `forall` are brought into scope.