# Composing functions with a intermediate polymorphic type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, function-composition

I have the following file:

```hs
module SimpleComposition where

class Intermediate a where
    f :: a -> Int
    g :: Char -> a

h :: Char -> Int
h = f . g
```

When trying loading it in ghci, I get the error:

```
main.hs:8:5: error:
    * No instance for (Intermediate a0) arising from a use of `f'
    * In the first argument of `(.)', namely `f'
      In the expression: f . g
      In an equation for `h': h = f . g
  |
8 | h = f . g
  |     ^
```

I believe the problem is that someone could be using 2 different types which are instances of `Intermediate` in this composition. How can I guarantee it is the same when I export this module?

PS: This is a better minimal example of the problem I have than the question I asked before ([How to compose polymorphic functions in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65362659/5725148)).

Comment: The problem is that Haskell does not know what `a` to use as intermediate.

Comment: The answers give solutions to the error, but I think don't explain the problem that's implied by the error. So let me take a stab at that as a supplement to the fixes. Suppose I write `instance Intermediate () where {f _ = 0; g _ = ();}; instance Intermediate Bool where {f _ = 1; g _ = False;}`. What behavior do you expect `h` to have there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I believe the problem is that someone could be using 2 different types which are instances of Intermediate in this composition.

No the problem is that Haskell can no longer derive from the signature what `a` to use. Imagine that there are two `Intermediate` types:

```
instance Intermediate Char where
    # …

instance Intermediate Bool where
    # …
```

now there are two implementations for `h`:

```
h :: Char -> Int
h = f . (g :: Char -> Char)
```

or:

```
h :: Char -> Int
h = f . (g :: Char -> Bool)
```

there can be an infinite number of `Intermediate` types that can be used. The problem is that Haskell can not tell, based on the type signature what type to use.

We can give it a type hint, but that of course means that the intermediate type is fixed.

A simple way to fix this is making use of [**`asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:asTypeOf). This is basically a `const` function, but where the two parameters have the same type. This is thus used to add a hint what type to use, for example:

```
h :: Intermediate a => a -> Char -> Int
h a x = f (g x `asTypeOf` a)
```

Here the *value* `a` parameter is thus not of any importance, this is a way to "inject" the type that will be used as type for the result of `g` and the parameter of `f`.

If you thus later use `h`, you can work with:

```
h (undefined :: Char) 'a'
```

to specify that `f` should have type `Char -> Char`, and `g` should have type `Char -> Int`.

Like [@leftroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65374433/composing-functions-with-a-intermediate-polymorphic-type-in-haskell/65374567?noredirect=1#comment115578476_65374567) and [@DanielWagner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65374433/composing-functions-with-a-intermediate-polymorphic-type-in-haskell/65374567?noredirect=1#comment115578565_65374567) say, a more clean solution without making use of such *dummy variable*, is adding the type variable in the signature:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}

h :: forall a. Intermediate a => Char -> Int
h = f . g @ a
```

then we can use `h` with a type variable with:

```
h @ Char 'a'
```

Comment: I'm not keen on the suggestion to pass in a dummy parameter. At least mention the `ScopedTypeVariables` / `AllowAmbiguousTypes` version of that too (or the one with proxies if you prefer, though IMO proxies are obsolete too).

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I'm not sure `AllowAmbiguousTypes` here can solve the problem? The idea is here to enable "accessing" the intermediate type when we *use* `h` as a function, not when we define it. Such that a person later can decide if the data flows "through" a `Char` or a `Bool`, and not decide that where we *define* the `h` function.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, `AllowAmbiguousTypes` solves that problem. (In fact, that's the exact problem it was designed to solve.) Writing `h :: Intermediate a => Char -> Int` allows the caller to say `h @String` (or whatever).

Comment: @DanielWagner: well I tried that, and get `Could not deduce (Intermediate a0) arising from a use of ‘f’ from the context: Intermediate a`, I tried it with `h = f . id @a . g`, and using `ScopedTypeVariables`, `TypeApplications`, but likely due to some sort of brainfreeze, I don't get it working: https://repl.it/@willemvo/ambiguous#main.hs

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you forgot the `∀ a`. (Such a brainfreeze [would never happen to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176037/scopedtypevariables-fail-to-work-with-nested-where-clauses)...).

Comment: A better version of the dummy argument approach is the proxy argument approach. `asProxyTypeOf :: a -> proxy a -> a; asProxyTypeOf a _ = a`. Importing `Data.Proxy`, you can write ``a `asProxyTypeOf` (Proxy :: Proxy Int)`` or similar.

Answer (score 5):

The problem isn't really that the instance can't be inferred, but that the compiler really has no way of knowing what type you could possibly want there. `g` can produce any type that's asked from it (provided it has an `Intermediate` instance), `f` can consume any such type... but nobody specifies *which one*.

But that's easy to fix: just select a type now. Of course it needs to be one that does have an instance; e.g. if you have

```
instance Intermediate Char where
  f = fromEnum
  g = id
```

then you can use

```
h :: Char -> Int
h = (f :: Char -> Int) . g
```

A more concise way of fixing the type choice is to use a syntactic extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

h = f @Char . g
```

...or, to emphasize that you're just fixing the type in the middle,

```
h = f . id @Char . g
```